# Error downloading file from internet using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am recevining an authorization error on the below code. When I change the download location to C:\temp I do not get this error. See below code and error.

I need to download to the files to the D drive as it is a shared folder

Changing to the C drive worked but I need it to be downloaded to the D drive

```
$File64 = "https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=121721&arch=x64"
$Location64 = "D:\temp\mpam-fe64Bit.exe"
$File32 = "https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=121721&arch=x86"
$Location32 = "D:\temp\mpam-fe32Bit.exe"

$Client = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$Client.DownloadFile($File64, $Location64)  

$Client.DownloadFile($File32, $Location32)
```

The error I receive is below

> Exception calling "DownloadFile" with "2" argument(s): "The remote
>   server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized." At
>   C:\PSScripts\DownloadDefs.ps1:9 char:1
>   + $Client.DownloadFile($File32, $Location32)
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
> - CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
> - FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebException

I tried adding the below code but it still does not work

```
$credCache = new-object System.Net.CredentialCache
$creds = new-object System.Net.NetworkCredential($user,$pwd)
$credCache.Add($source, "Basic", $creds)
$wc.Credentials = $credCache
```

Any help at all would be greatly appreciate

Comment: I assume your "D:" drive is mapped drive on another server? How are you executing the code? What credentials are you using to run it?

Comment: I run the script directly from the server so the D drive is a physical drive. The credentials I use is the administrator account

Comment: Ok, if it works simply replacing C: with D: then all I can think of is check share permissions as well as file permissions on the folder in D: (they're not the same thing).